# SyncFusion TreeGrid ContextMenu doesn't seem to work with vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, syncfusion, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to add a context menu to my SyncFusion TreeGrid, but nothing seems to happen.
This is what my file looks like:

```
<template>
<ej2-treegrid
    :dataSource="tabla"
    :contextMenuItems="contextMenuItems"
    rowHeight="20px"
    ><e-columns>
        <e-column field="nombre" headerText="Nombre"></e-column>
        <e-column field="cantidad" headerText="Cantidad"></e-column>
        <e-column field="vu" headerText="Valor Unitario" format="C"></e-column>
        <e-column field="precio" headerText="Precio" format="C"></e-column>
    </e-columns>
</ej2-treegrid>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, reactive, provide } from "vue";
import { TreeGridComponent as ej2Treegrid,
    ColumnsDirective as eColumns,
    ColumnDirective as eColumn,
    ContextMenu,
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-treegrid';

provide("treegrid", [ContextMenu]);

const contextMenuItems = ["Cancel"];

const tabla = reactive([{id: 1, nombre: "", cantidad: 2, vu: 2, precio: 2}]);
</script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Maybe is the provide part? The documentation seems to be for vue2.

When I right click on the grid, the default context menu appears. I've had similar problems with editting.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that the context menu module is not injected properly. Based on your shared code example, we checked, and the provide part returns an error. So, we suggest you follow the code example below.

Your code:

```
provide("treegrid", [ContextMenu]);
```

Modified code:

```
provide: {
  treegrid: [Page, ContextMenu, Edit,],
}
```

And we have prepared a simple Vue3 sample with context menu and editing.
 Please refer to the below sample:
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Vue_3_context_menu-200508808